# Microsoft Access: 2 records excluding 1 based on certain criteria

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have 1 table. I want to develop a query that filters out the Dog record if the ID has more than one record. If the ID has only 1 record, then keep the dog record.

```
ID  | AnimalType
401 | Dog
401 | Cat
401 | Bird
402 | Dog
403 | Cat
404 | Dog
404 | Bird
```

The result of the query would be...

```
ID | AnimalType
401| Cat
401| Bird
402| Dog
403| Cat
404| Bird
```

Comment: Need better description.

Comment: Thanks @PaulFrancis. I edited the description with an end result. Does that help? Sorry, this is my first question on here.

Comment: Are you only worried about **Dog** what in future you want to eliminate **Cat** and **Dog**? Why not Dog with ID 401? Why Dog with ID 402 and not 404? Providing sample data is fine, but give some data that actually makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to accomplish this:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.AnimalType
FROM tblAnimals A
INNER JOIN ( SELECT ID, COUNT(1) as IDCount FROM tblAnimals GROUP BY ID ) T
  ON A.ID = T.ID
WHERE NOT (T.IDCount>1 and A.AnimalType='Dog')
```

The basic idea is to get a count per ID of records in a subquery, then we can apply the exact logic of filtering out the case if "animal is a dog and there is more than one record for that ID".

Demo: **http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/db6a9/2** (in SQL Server, not Access, but the logic is the same)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to accomplish this would be using a `NOT EXISTS` function when you hit a dog record to determine if any other animals exist at the same ID:

```
SELECT ID, AnimalType
FROM Animals t1
WHERE AnimalType <> 'Dog' Or NOT EXISTS ( SELECT ID FROM Animals t2 WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID And AnimalType <> 'Dog' );
```